# R heatmap.2: How do I adjust ylim of the histogram on the color key?

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

For reasons of comparison of two heatmaps associating categorical variables, I would like to know how I can adjust the "Count" axis of the density plot/histogram superimposed on the color key such that in both heatmaps the keys including the histogram are more easily comparable?

I would expect to have something like

```
heatmap.2( 
   ...
   key.ylim=c(min,max),
   ...
)
```

available but it seems as if this is hardcoded in `heatmap.2`. I am not sure whether I can do this via `key.ytickfun` or `key.par`.

Thank you for an answer.

Comment: use the `breaks=seq(min, max, length.out=length)` option?

Comment: @Peyman: As far as I understood and tried, `breaks` would allow me to adjust the number of bins of the histogram = number of colors along the x-axis, right? However, I am looking for a way to adjust the y-axis settings.